# Calling a handler in JS to get upload file progress

Tags: asp.net, ihttphandler

I have a form with an embeded iframe which points to a upload.aspx. During the upload that happens within the iframe, I'm trying to get the progress of the upload by implementing my own HttpHandler, however, the request is blocked until the upload completes.

Is there a request limit that I can change in the web.config? Is this even the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to implement HttpModule. Read here:
[HttpHandler or HttpModule for file upload, large files, progress indicator?](http://forums.asp.net/t/55127.aspx)